# Elastic search > Groovy script > Nested Fields with multiple result in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, groovy, foselasticabundle

How to add condition and get value of **FeeAmount** nested field in totalRate?
I have used Fos-elastica bundle in symfony

**Elastic search mapping**

```
profile:
  mappings:
    id: ~
    title: ~
    name: ~
    rates:
        type: "nested"
        properties:
            id: ~
            serviceName: ~
            FeeAmount:
                type: "float"
```

I want condition as per i have written in below code for Groovy script.
Here, _source.rates() returns multiple results so i need to add separate condition for each rates service

```
    $elasticaClient = new \Elastica\Client();
    $search = new \Elastica\Search($elasticaClient);
    $search->addIndex('COC');
    $search->addType('Profile');

    $mainQuery = new \Elastica\Query(); // main query

    // Start Groovy Script

    $scriptString = "total = 0;
        for (pos in _source.rates()) {
            if(pos.id == 1){
                total = total + pos.FeeAmount;
            }
        }
        return total;";

    $script = new \Elastica\Script($scriptString);
    $script->setLang('groovy');

    $mainQuery->setFields(['_source']);
    $mainQuery->setScriptFields([ 'totalRate' => $script]);

    $search->setQuery($mainQuery);

    $results = $search->search()->getResults();

    return $results;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by google..

```
 $scriptString = "total = 0;
    for (pos in _source.rates()) {
        if(pos.id == 1){
            total = total + pos.FeeAmount;
        }
    }
    return total;";
```

Replace above code with this one, and it's works

```
$scriptString = "
    def total = 0;
    for (rate in _source.rates) {
        total = total + rate.FeeAmount;
    }
    return total;";
```